# What is the workaround for OCaml: exception Invalid_argument("Random.int")?

Tags: random, int, arguments, ocaml

I have this bit of code:

```
let rec random_list = function
  | 0 -> []
  | n -> ( Random.int max_int ) :: ( random_list (n-1) )
```

It compiles okay, but when I execute it, this error shows up:

```
exception Invalid_argument("Random.int")
```

What is the workaround for this issue ?

Answer (score 11):

The [documentation](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Random.html) says:

> `Random.int bound` returns a random integer between `0` (inclusive) and `bound` (exclusive). `bound` must be greater than `0` and less than `2^30`.

So the closest to what you want is:

```
let my_max_int = (1 lsl 30) - 1 in
Random.int my_max_int
```

---

As gsg suggested, using `Random.bits ()` is cleaner to get almost the same result (it can also return `2^30 - 1`).

If you really want to get any positive native integer, maybe you could use `Random.nativeint`, but this means you would have to use the module `Nativeint` and `Nativeint.t` instead of `int`.

Comment: You are welcome. I improved my answer with a way to write `2^30 - 1` in an effective way.

Comment: `Random.bits ()` is a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: Oh yes, I will add it to my answer then.

Comment: `Random.bits ()` is not the same as the above, because `Random.bits ()` generates a random 30-bit positive integer, which can produce 2^30-1, whereas `Random.int ((1 lsl 30) - 1)` cannot produce 2^30-1.

Comment: My experience to share: I tried `Random.bits()` and `let my_max_int = (1 lsl 30) - 1 ` and got `stackoverflow`. I changed it to  `let my_max_int = (1 lsl 25) - 1 ` and the error stops.